# WSO2 Identity Server - disable case-insensitve username

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 5.10.0 and I configured it in order to use a JDBC User Store. The RDBMS is PostgreSQL.

I noticed that WSO2 IS is using a case-insensitive username strategy to let the access to the resources. Basically I can user my username all in uppercase or lowercase and I'll always be able in get the access. I need strongly to avoid this. I tried what there is written here https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-the-authorization-manager/#configuring-the-authorization-manager_1 but I can always get the access by using case-insensitive usernames

Is there any configuration I'm missing? Or is this the only way to get the access?

Angelo

**EDIT**

As suggested i changed my user store as I show:

```
#COME PRIMARY STORE USO IL DB POSTGRESQL
[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://XXXX:YYYY/wso2is_primary_user_store"
username = "user"
password = "pwd"
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
properties.CaseInsensitiveUsername = false
```

I tried to access with an user both by using username in lower case and in upper case.

**EDIT 2**

I changed the `deoplyment.toml` in this way:

```
#COME PRIMARY STORE USO IL DB POSTGRESQL
[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"
properties.CaseInsensitiveUsername=false

[database.user]
url = "jdbc:postgresql://xxx:yyy/wso2is_primary_user_store"
username = "username"
password = "password"
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"


[realm_manager]
data_source = "WSO2USER_DB"
```

In this way for new users usernames are case sensitive. For old users usernames seem to remain case insensitive. I need to deeply investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in WSO2 Identity Sever the Case Insensitive Username configuration is in active state. You can deactivate that configuration by adding the following configuration to the **deployement.toml** file located in **IS-HOME/repository/conf/deployement.toml** location.

```
[user_store]
properties.CaseInsensitiveUsername = false
```

Also if you need to change the configurations for a JDBC User Store please refer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-a-jdbc-user-store/

Comment: I didn't find the `properties.CaseInsensitiveUsername` propeprty inside the documentation. In any case, as you can see in my EDIT, i modified the `deployment.toml` file as I showed and I still can login by using case insensitive usernames. Am I missing anything?

Comment: As you are trying to create a JDBC User Store please refer this document https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-a-jdbc-user-store/ to configure it. You can find the PostgreSQL configuration from there too. Also you can find the other JDBC configurations please refer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-a-jdbc-user-store/#properties-used-in-jdbc-user-store-manager.

Comment: I followed the link you gave to me (I have an error when I try to use [realm_manager]
data_source = "WSO2USER_DB"... where to configure this JNDI name?) Nothing to do.. I still can login by using case insensitive usernames. What else can I do?

Comment: As the question you are trying to configure a JDBC User Store by using PostgreSQL with WSO2 Identity Server. But the document that you have mentioned in the question is configuring an authorization manager. Could you please verify your requirement?

Comment: Ops.. I'm so sorry... I used the wrong link. I confirm I'm configuring an JDBC user store. I confirm I followed this link https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-a-jdbc-user-store/#configuring-a-jdbc-user-store and the postgreSQL section. I only have an issue because if in my `deployment.toml` I leave `[realm_manager] data_source = "WSO2USER_DB"` WSO2 IS doesn't find this JNDI name. I confirm I added the property `properties.CaseInsensitiveUsername` and you can find my `deployment.toml` in my **EDIT** section. But, after this, I still can log in with case insensitive username

Comment: The configurations in **deployement.toml** of the **EDIT** section is different than this document https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-a-jdbc-user-store/#configuring-a-jdbc-user-store. In this document there are several configurations that needs to add to the **deployement.toml** file to configure a PostgreSQL. Please follow the PostgreSQL section in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-a-jdbc-user-store/#configuring-an-external-database-as-jdbc-user-store.

Comment: OK... being in a hurry means to do mistakes. I changed the deployment.toml by slavishly following the documentation. The old users seem to be able in logging in case insensitive way. For new users usernames are case sensitive. I modified the deployment.toml like in the EDIT 2 section